# WSO2 ESB returning HTTP/1.1 413 Request Too Long for GET with url of 8k characters

Tags: tomcat, wso2, wso2-esb

I am receiving an HTTP 413 error when sending a GET request to an API deployed on WSO2 ESB (version 4.8.1). The URL of the GET is of the form http://host:port/transaction-monitoring/userid/{userid}/sessionid/{sessionid}.

The userid and sessionid values are up to 4000 characters long. Appreciate that this API would be better as a POST but we are constrained to using the GET. The problem happen when the userid and sessionid near 4000 characters. With other headers in the request it looks like the underlying tomcat connector maxHttpHeaderSize is being exceeded (default 8192).

I have increased this to 65536 in the catalina-server.xml but this make no difference to the result. It is as if the value in the catalina-server.xml is being ignored and the default 8192 limit appears to be used. Has anyone experienced/resolved similar? Is there another tomcat value that could be changed?